# Making Yii2 as SSO server

Tags: yii2, single-sign-on

I want to make a server of SSO which will be used as central of 4 others app to login and logout, and this is the first time i make app like this.

Lets say i have A B and C app which will ask SSO for session available.

I develop SSO using Yii2, and now i have made a route open for the other 4 apps to connect.

But the problem is, it doesn't give me any data.

I have tried provide `Yii::$app->user->identity->` and `session`, but it doesn't work..

Can you give me suggestion, or anything about this?

Comment: Show a code sample, and explain your goal..

Comment: is this apps used different domains or in  one  domain multiple subdomains e.g: app1.apps.com , app2.apps.com ...

Comment: thats the problem,.
i don't know yet,.
so i just prepare for worst case (app1.com,app2.com and so on..)

Comment: @ scaisEdge i just started, and just thingking about it flows,..

Comment: In this case u  can use subdomains and configure user session domain as a .app.com in your configuration web.php file. Take a look at this : http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/135/single-sign-on-across-multiple-subdomains/

Comment: sorry but i dont get it??

Comment: @RyanArief are you going to use subdomains? because i think my answer only work with subdomains.(I tested them only subdomains). If yes i will post answer.

Comment: no, they will have their own server

Comment: So in this case u must use something like oauth or custom api for this app for login from single interface